# Is duplication of declarations still a problem in C++?

Tags: c++

Okay so I recently learned how the compiler exactly works and what the "linker" is. From the tutorial videos I've watched I clearly saw that if I include more than once a declaration, to say:

```
void Log(const char* message);
```

I would get an error since I am declaring it more than once. But currently, as I am testing it, I've created a header file which contains that particular declaration and I've included it a couple of times in my Main compilation unit, as so:

```
#include "Log.h"
#include "Log.h"
```

I have removed the #pragma once statement, nor do I have header guards written, but my program still runs perfectly and without any problems. Since the videos are 2-3 years old, I thought maybe there has been an update, which alltogether removes the need of guards and pragmas, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: `void Log(const char* message);` is a declaration, not a definition. Try replacing `;` with `{}` and you'll get your error.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant exactly declaration, not definition. Will edit it right now.

Comment: Multiple declarations was never a problem, though, so this correction invalidates the premise of your question.

Comment: You can have as many declarations of all matter of symbols as you like, it's the *definitions* that's the problem. Read about [the One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule). I also recommend you learn about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), as the One Definition Rule is per program, and spans multiple translation units.

Comment: I most definitely will check it out. Other than that a know, at a basic level what a translation unit is. Basically the .cpp file that gets converted to .obj file and then used by the linker to create the .exe file. It does not know of other .cpp until the linker comes in play. After reading all of the answers of my thread, I went back to review the video and saw that the programmer has included a whole definition of that function in the header file. I just thought that it was a declaration and remembered it so. My mistake. I am pretty new to programming and to C++ even more so please spare me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would get an error since I am declaring it more than once.

Re-declaration is generally allowed, as long as you don't mix different kinds of declarations with the same name. Following is perfectly legal C++, and always has been:

```
void Log(const char* message); 
void Log(const char* message);
```

You may have been confused with the one **definition** rule, which disallows **defining** things more than once.

> I have removed the #pragma once statement, nor do I have header guards written, but my program still runs perfectly and without any problems.

If your header doesn't define anything, then it doesn't need a header guard. It's however simpler to just conventionally always keep the guard so that there is no need to keep track of whether there are definitions or not.

---

Bonus answer: All definitions are also declarations. It is usually easy to distinguish definitions of classes and functions from forward declarations:

```
return_type function_name(argument_list);        // not a definition of function
return_type function_name(argument_list) { ... } // is  a definition of function

class class_name;                                // not a definition of class
class class_name {                               // is  a definition of class
    void member_function();                      // not a definition of function
    void inline_member_function() { ... };       // is  a definition of function
};
void class_name::member_function() { ... }       // is  a definition of function
```

Distinguishing variable definitions is a bit harder. Always check the rules when unsure.

Comment: I have a question though. I understood that if I don't have definitions, I don't need a header guard, but ... Wouldn't it be still of use to write one, since it will guard you from having repeated lines of code? Multiple declarations of a function to say would take more memory than only one declaration, right?

Comment: @DimitarMitranov The effect on difference in memory use or time of compilation would probably be negligible. Bigger benefit is not having to continually keep checking whether you have your header guards when you add definitions to your header files.

Answer (score 6):

The tutorials you've seen are correct.  You cannot have more than one definition of something unless you use special techniques.

In this case though you don't have a definition.

```
void Log(const char* message);
```

is a declaration and you are allowed to have multiples of those.  If you change the code to

```
void Log(const char* message) {}
```

then you would have a function definition and will get an error.

Comment: But this function comes from a header, so it is supposed to be `inline` or function template. No point to extract a function into a header if it cannot be reused.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I'm sorry but I don't get your comment.  I'm showing the OP that if they did do `void Log(const char* message) {}`, then they would see the multiple definition error they expected to get.

Comment: I misremembered the tutotial I saw yesterday, while I was doing the tests today. I thought that the programmer just used a declaration in the header file and still got errors while including it in multiple cpp files. Seem's my memory did me a trick. Thank you for the clarification thought, it is certainly most helpful.

Comment: @DimitarMitranov No problem.  C++ is pretty complex so it's easy to get things mixed up when you start learning.

Answer (score 0):

Cherno's tutorials?

I think its made crystal clear in the videos that you can't have multiple definitions of a function. The custom header files that you've created are basically chunks of code copy-pasted hence if they include different definitions of the same function or say class it will result in ambiguity and throw an error as expected.

**Edit:** The point that he wanted to make -
If you write those two same function definitions together in a file then obviously it will throw up an error due to ambiguity arising as I mentioned above, which is detected by the **compiler**, since its only in a single file.

But when you place those two same definitions in a different file, say your custom created header "log.h" then when you import them into your cpp file twice (or say you import them in another cpp file and build the solution like in visual studio) it will throw up a linker error as the **linker** is involved (multiple files - wherein the job of the linker is to link them into a combined executable) and it cannot select multiple definitions present in different files. Hence for this case you will get the multiple definitions/signature error. (And including pragmas suppress warnings)

A Solution to resolve that is making the functions static, so that they are defined internally or only for the file they are being compiled against. This makes it possible to have multiple function definitions of the same function in different files with no linking error. Another option is to make it in-line. These cases provide you with multiple definitions with no errors, otherwise it will throw up errors.

Comment: Exactly his :D . The problem is that I misremembered his linker video when I did the tests on my own today. I remembered him using only a declaration in the Log.h file, but after reading all of you comments I went back and saw that it is a whole declaration, which means I've lived in a lie these 2 days. Thank you all for the clarification. I know it is a useless post, but it corrected my view point.

Comment: I followed the whole series till the end, its one of the best resources to learn C++. Its okay to live a lie as long as you get the truth in the end :) I edited the post from the linker's point of view - will make it clear.

Comment: @DimitarMitranov Minor nitpick, on terminology: Didn't you mean "definition" instead of "_whole declaration_"? Declaration is declaration. Using correct terminology will lead to less miscommunications, so it's better to start using it correctly, from the get-go.

Comment: Yes, you should make the change from 'declaration' to 'definition', both in the title as well as question, as the former isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

this a [function forward declaration](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/73378/) and you just let the compiler know that a function X will be defined later. in some resources you will find out it's written/said that multiple declaration isn't allowed, but i think cuz of the clean code approach, not a compiler issue. and your case, you just include the declaration twice, the same if you declared the function in two different header files and included both of them in a source file.